# Start application after Amiga Workbench 1.3 boot sequence

Tags: amiga, boot, amiga-shell, amiga-workbench-1.3

I want to start an application after the boot sequence of `Workbench1.3`:

[image]

In my case an `Amiga Shell` application:

[image]

Where are the startup files located and what are the changes to provide this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should start by adding your chosen commands to `S/User-Startup` on your boot volume. You can also refer to it as `S:User-Startup`; `S:` will redirect to the S directory on the boot volume. This will definitely work on Workbench 2.04 and later, and may also work on earlier versions too (some application software "backports" the necessary support to Workbench 1.3 systems).

The command you want to add is simply:

```
NewShell
```

If this doesn't work, then your system most likely doesn't support S/User-Startup. This is normal on the earlier Workbench versions. In this case you'll have to make a change to the system startup file. This is called `S/Startup-Sequence` on your boot volume.

The last lines of this file, by default, will be something like this:

```
LoadWB DELAY
EndCLI >NIL:
```

If you add the command `NewShell` in between these two lines, it should do what you are looking for.

Comment: It is worth adding to this that if you are targeting OS 2.04 or later, then you should modify S:User-Startup instead of S:Startup-Sequence as the latter became relegated to operating system bits (and thus subject to change by OS upgrades) and the new user-startup is meant for whatever you want to put in. OS 1.3 didn't have the user-startup file.